# Blackberry SQLite Cursor after db change

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, cursor

I use blackberry SQLite.
I get a Cursor from Statement query to DB by `myStatement.getCursor()`.
I hold it to get data from it.

Then the DB changes, before I got data from Cursor. What happens if I do getRow() then?

How can I know that the DB has changed and I should re`getCursor` to get data?

This can be illustrated with this snippet

```
Statement myStatement = someDb.createStatement(someSql);
Cursor myCursor = myStatement.getCursor();
// ...
// db is changed somewhere in this code
// ...
// and here I get data from Cursor with moveToNext/getInt for example
```

Comment: Can you give more clarity on your question..it is hard to understand..

Comment: edited a question. Don't know how to clarify it better than this

Comment: why are you changing the db? my understanding is cursor holds a virtual read only table, so that you can access each row. if you want to access another database then I think you should create another statement and create new cursor object..